# Angular JS copy Object to another into a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, object

Trying to copy a part of a json object into another json object (thats a filter), into a for loop, under a conditional statement, it doesn't work.

This work but a plain to write an array:

```
$scope.candidats=[];
for (i=0;i<omegaCandidats.length;i++){
    if (omegaCandidats[i].dateRdv==date){ 
        $scope.candidats.push(
            {
             "id"       :omegaCandidats[i].id,
             "prenom"   :omegaCandidats[i].prenom,
             "nom"      :omegaCandidats[i].nom,
             "heure"    :omegaCandidats[i].heure,
             "dateRdv"  :omegaCandidats[i].date
            }
        )
    };
};
```

This doesn't work, and that's what i want to do. Its logical and should work:

```
$scope.candidats=[];
for (i=0;i<omegaCandidats.length;i++){
    if (omegaCandidats[i].dateRdv==date){ 
        $scope.candidats[i] = omegaCandidats[i];
    };
};
```

This one work but only get one value of the for loop its useless:

```
$scope.candidats=[];
for (i=0;i<omegaCandidats.length;i++){
    if (omegaCandidats[i].dateRdv==date){ 
        $scope.candidats[0] = omegaCandidats[i];
    };
};
```

Comment: Do not forget to accept answers (I say this also for your old questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work :

```
$scope.candidats=[];
    for (i=0;i<omegaCandidats.length;i++){

        if (omegaCandidats[i].dateRdv==date){ 

            //$scope.candidats.push(omegaCandidats[i]);

            $scope.candidats.push(angular.copy(omegaCandidats[i]));
            //copy will create a new reference for your object.
        };
    };
```

The code you had is not logical to me :

```
$scope.candidats=[];
    for (i=0;i<omegaCandidats.length;i++){
        if (omegaCandidats[i].dateRdv==date){ 
            $scope.candidats[i] = omegaCandidats[i]; // This can't work because $scope.candidats[i] is not defined.
            // You would also have an inconsistent array
        };
    };
```

Comment: Woow thanks a lot let's try this and the others solutions too, u're awesome tx a lot !

Comment: I've edited my answer. I'm not sure if you need to copy or not your values.

Comment: Yees ! It works u're really great thank a lot, it will save me a lot of times, i'll try the filters too it's more logical. Angular is fantastic.

Comment: yup, for this particular problem, a filter is more suitable

Comment: True about the inconsistent array, I agree ! Thank you again a lot. it will help for my project http://nicolash.org/angular/app7.html

Comment: https://nicolashcodes.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/micro-application-7-evalentretien-avec-angular-bootstrap-restphp/

Answer (score 3):

what about using a filter:

```
$scope.candidats = omegaCandidats.filter(function(candidat){ 
    return candidat.dateRdv == date;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter array method, try this:

```
$scope.candidats = omegaCandidats.filter(function(item) {
    return item.dateRdv==date;
});
```

Comment: :) beat you by 8 seconds

Comment: Thank you a lot, you are impressive !